# Trouble installing scipy on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, scipy

I've installed new instance of python-2.7.2 with brew. Installed numpy from pip, then from sources. I keep getting

numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config.PkgNotFound: Could not find file(s) ['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini']

when I try to install scipy, either from sources or by pip, and it drives me mad.

Scipy's binary installer tells me, that python 2.7 is required and that I don't have it (I have 2 versions installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EPD distribution saved the day.